# Segue using tableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am going to try to be as clear as I can be on this question but if you need more information please please ask. I have a tableviewcontroller that has a list of all the messages the logged in user has had with other users of the app. When clicked the logged in user clicks a cell, I would like for the user to segue to a view controller that allows them to chat with whatever user they like. This chat was acquired using JSQMessageController. However, when I set it the segue in the tableviewcontroller, show below:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

             let message = messages[indexPath.row]

            if message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid {
                var newVariable = message.ReceiverId

                if self.userpicuid ==  newVariable {

                    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userpicuid!)

                    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                        in

                        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                            for post in dictionary {
                                let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                                for (id, value) in messages {

                                    self.username = messages["username"] as? String


                                }}}})}} else if message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid {
                let newVariable = message.senderId

                if self.userpicuid ==  newVariable {

                    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userpicuid!)

                    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                        in

                        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                            for post in dictionary {
                                let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                                for (id, value) in messages {

                                    self.username = messages["username"] as? String
                                }}}})}

            }

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MessageNow", sender: self.userpicuid)

    }


    override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "MessageNow", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
            return
        }

        chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
        chatVc.receiverData = sender as AnyObject
        chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.userpicuid
        chatVc.username = self.username

    }
```

I get an error in the MessageViewController:

```
 var receiverData: AnyObject?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let receiverId = receiverData as! String
        let receiverIdFive = String(receiverId.characters.prefix(5))
        let senderIdFive = String(senderId.characters.prefix(5))
        if (senderIdFive > receiverIdFive)
        {
            self.convoId = senderIdFive + receiverIdFive
        }
        else
        {
            self.convoId = receiverIdFive + senderIdFive
        }}
```

I get the error on the let receiverId = receiverData as! String that:
**Could not cast value of type 'Chat_App.MessageTableViewCell' (0x10eb2ef10) to 'NSString' (0x110ab1c60).**

in a different view controller, I have:

```
 @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendMessageToUser", sender: self.userpicuid)
}

override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "sendMessageToUser", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
        return
    }

    chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
    chatVc.receiverData = sender as! String!
    chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.userpicuid
    chatVc.username = self.username

}
```

And it segues perfectly.

Comment: how did you declare `receiverData`?

Comment: @f_qi   var receiverData: AnyObject?

Comment: Sender is a `UITableViewCell`. You can't cast that to an `NSString`.

Comment: @nighttalker  
in a different view controller, I have the exact same thing but it works. I can't show you the code in this comment, so I have updated it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `sender` is the the `UITableViewCell` that initiated the segue. You are crashing when casting it to `NSString`. Remove this line

```
let receiverId = receiverData as! String
```

In `prepareForSegue` do this instead

```
chatVc.receiverData = self.userpicuid
```

Comment: I did this and now I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the same line

Comment: in which line ?

Comment: let receiverId = receiverData as! String

Comment: yeah, you need to remove that line.

Comment: I can't its key to sending my messages to firebase database

Comment: receiverData is not your key, it is the cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145501/discussion-between-juelizabeth-and-joze-ws).

Answer (score 0):

Sender is Any? and you're casting it to AnyObject. AnyObject refers to a class type, and it's asserting when you attempt to cast it to a Swift value type (String).

Try this instead:

```
chatVc.receiverData = NSString(string: sender as! String)
```